# Override the default implementation for a single field of a struct using `#[derive(Debug)]`

Tags: rust, obfuscation, rust-macros

I have a struct containing general config data for a web application:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct AppConfig {
  pub db_host: String,
  pub timeout: Duration,
  pub jwt_signing_key: String,
  // more fields
}
```

`jwt_signing_key` is a symmetric jwt secret, so much be kept confidential/

This works fine, but I would like to be able to log the contents of an `AppConfig` for debugging purposes without the JWT secret appearing in logs. Ideally, it would return something along the lines of:

```rust
AppConfig {
  db_host: "https://blah"
  jwt_signing_key: "**********"  // key obfuscated
}
```

One option is to create a thin wrapper:

```rust
pub struct AppConfig {
  // ...
  pub jwt_signing_key: JwtSigningKey,
}

pub struct JwtSigningKey(String);
// custom implementation of Debug
```

But this would require a large-ish refactor and adds an unnecessary (in my opinion) layer of indirection. (I'm not worried about the performance, but more the code noise)

`AppConfig` is relatively large and maintaining a manual `Debug` implementation is extra work I'd rather not have to do every time I want to add a field.

Is there an easier solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One option is to create a thin wrapper:
>
> ```rust
> pub struct AppConfig {
>   // ...
>   pub jwt_signing_key: JwtSigningKey,
> }
>
> pub struct JwtSigningKey(String);
> // custom implementation of Debug
> ```

I think you should go with this option. The advantage it has is that *no matter where in your application the value ends up,* it will never be accidentally printed — or used in any other way — without explicitly unwrapping it, whereas replacing `Debug` of the `AppConfig` struct will only assist with that one particular case. It's robust against mistakes made while refactoring, too.

The type doesn't have to be so specific as `JwtSigningKey`; it could be just `pub struct Secret<T>(T);` and support any kind of secrets you end up working with. There are even [libraries to provide such a type (see this thread for comments comparing two of them)](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/hnnm5c/ann_secrecy_v070_a_simple_secretkeeping_library/) which add more features like zeroing the memory when dropped (so that it's less likely that any accidental leak of memory contents might reveal a secret).

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/37009) thread. Essentially, the best way to do it right now is to use the [`derivative`](https://crates.io/crates/derivative) crate, which allows you to do something like this:

```rust
use derivative::Derivative;
use std::fmt;

fn obfuscated_formatter(val: &str, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
    write!(f, "{:?}", "*".repeat(val.len()))
}

#[derive(Derivative)]
#[derivative(Debug)]
struct Foo {
    normal: String,
    #[derivative(Debug(format_with = "obfuscated_formatter"))]
    secret: String
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo {
        normal: "asdf".into(),
        secret: "foobar".into()
    };
    println!("{:?}", foo);
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f32087f688f22f8d657f6bfe61b86b17)